# How to move camera to a marker on map when clicking marker name from search suggustions on map api v2?

Tags: android, search, google-maps-api-2

I was working on ATM locator app and Marker name,latitude and longitude information is stored in sq lite database and the suggestion is working properly my problem is when marker name suggestion is clicked to move the camera to the position of the marker.I am trying to do it using cursor loader please help.

Comment: can you tell something about your "suggestion"? Normally a marker get focussed automatically when it gets clicked.

Comment: the suggestion is the marker name which is fetched from sq lite database and as i mentioned before the suggestion works but the problem is when the suggestion is clicked i want it to move the camera to the marker's lat,long point which is stored in sqlite database along with the marker name in the same row in the database.